# How long does a question ban last here in my case?

Tags: support, moderator

I have posted to many questions that was not high quality. What else can I do to earn to privilege back other than revising my posts? Some of them are as good as I can make them for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [FAQ](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans):

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

Aside from that, I can only promise you I'll take a look at your improved questions and see if they merit any change in my votes. Keep looking to ask better questions. I think you are getting more specific, but there's still a bit of a lack of quality that is there.

Comment: You should try Engineering SE. Thanks so much